# How to disable weekdays and custom days in jquery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code below i need to disable the weekdays and also given days how can i do that ? Can some one help me ?

*Jquery* [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/irfanfiddle/JjPrU/854/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var Desingndate = $('#DesignIdUnavialble').html();
var splitdate = Desingndate.split(',');
   // console.log(splitdate.length);
    var arrDisabledDates = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < splitdate.length; i++) {
        //console.log(splitdate[i]);    
    arrDisabledDates[new Date(splitdate[i])] = new Date(splitdate[i]);    
    }

     $("#iDate").datepicker({       
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShowDay: function (dt) {
            var bDisable = arrDisabledDates[dt];
            if (bDisable) return [false, '', ''];
            else return [true, '', ''];
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/irfanfiddle/JjPrU/856/)

This may help you

```
function deadlinedates(date) {
      dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
      var day = date.getDay();

        var Desingndate = $('#DesignIdUnavialble').html();
        var splitdate = Desingndate.split(','); 
        var arrDisabledDates = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < splitdate.length; i++) {        
        arrDisabledDates[new Date(splitdate[i])] = new Date(splitdate[i]);    
        }

       var bDisable = arrDisabledDates[date];
       if (bDisable) return [false, '', ''];
       else return [(day != 0 && day != 6)];

    }


$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#iDate").datepicker({       
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShowDay: deadlinedates
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) once again it helped me thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this out [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-how-to-disable-weekdays)

I modified your else statement to disable all weekdays:

```
var bDisable = arrDisabledDates[dt];
if (bDisable) return [false, '', ''];
else {
    return [dt.getDay() == 6 || dt.getDay() == 0,""];
}
```

Comment: thanks but need to explain more and show the working demo